# I want to run java 7 compatible code on all downward java versions

Tags: java

I have coded an application in which I use some code specific to JAVA 7 only.The code use java.nio package which is in java 7 API only If I am not wrong . Now I want that when I make this application's exe this should run on any platform. Is it possible to do ? If not please explain me why it is not possible ? And what solution of this I should do ?

I have used SimpleFileVisitor API in my application.

Comment: How exactly do you make an exe ? Your question looks confused and if we read just the title, then the answer is simple : you can't.

Comment: By exe i meant any form of executable. Currently I only make jar file of the application from inside eclipse itself.So is it so that all who want to use my application will have to have java 7 on their machine ??

Comment: *"all downward java versions"*  Why would you want to run code on obsolete JREs?  I can understand down to (maybe) 1.5, but 1.1 through 1.4?

Comment: yes mostly it is ok with 1.5 ,no need from 1.1 through 1.4.and the reason I want to run code on obsolete JREs is that I am not sure that all the people who will use my application will have the java 7 installed on their machine.

Comment: It's not possible because the libraries simply aren't there. Provide them yourself in your program and you'll have them available or don't use them at all. That is assuming nothing gamebreaking changed to the language that is needed by that library. Try it and you'll see.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your application to work on any platform then you should not use libraries that are only on machines with Java 7. Write your own code, something that you are sure is on *any* version of Java.

Comment: Can't I package the required library in my application or something like that ?

Comment: Are you using third-party libraries? of course you can. If you are using JRE libraries no, you can't. You can probably use some of these: http://commons.apache.org/

Comment: @KRC You could go to the JRE librarys and copy-paste the code into your project.